# Windows 10: BIOS setting changed returning from hibernation

Tags: windows-10

I have a Dell machine (Precision Tower 5810) with an Intel Xeleron (E5-1607) processor and I recently installed Windows 10 (10.0.10240 Build 10240). It mostly works fine but when I return from hibernation I get a message like the one below.

[image: Error message displayed on return from hibernation]

"You have changed the settings in BIOS setup. Would you like to restart your computer to apply these changes?"

I usually just press cancel and be on my way but I'm curious as of why this happens if I can prevent it (because its annoying) and if there might be any problems on the system.

How can I prevent this from happening and what is happening?

Comment: try Win10 November update version 1511 (Build 10586) and look if this solves your issue

Comment: Downloading right now. Just to be clear this has been a problem since I first downloaded windows 10.

Comment: The new version does not solve this Im still getting the warning and I have still no idea where it comes from as there is no title bar on it.

Comment: Have you contacted Dell about this?

Comment: I haven't seen this since I upgraded windows 10 to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with a client on a Precision 5810 who when he resumes from hibernate receives exactly the same error. He is running Windows 7 Pro however.

That message is coming from some Dell software, so what I did was to uninstall everything that said Dell under Programs (except for drivers).

Comment: I have done the same allthough it din't help

Answer (score 2):

I've been annoyed by the same problem. Not having the full capabilities of the sound card was not an option for me. I used [support.dell.com](http://support.dell.com) to detect new drivers. For automatic detection, you are prompted to download "DellSystemDetect.exe".  My system tried to prevent me from installing this "unknown" software.  I had to choose to allow it anyway. Several updates were detected including a bios update which requires you to manually click on the installer and will force you to restart.  Happily, the problem has gone away after driver installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same problem with my machine. I used the system interal tools and found this message is coming from Realtek. I uninstalled the Realtek High Definition Audio Driver and the issue went away. The generic Windows Driver worked fine for Audio.

FYI... On Windows 10 the driver will reinstall itself. You will have to disable the auto update of drivers if you are running Windows 10.